# Custom Action for a custom Content Type's display form

Tags: 2010, ribbon, custom-actions

I have a custom action that I'd want to add to my custom display form of my custom content type

My custom action is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction
    Id="MyCustomRibbonTab"
    Location="DisplayFormToolbar"
    RegistrationId="0x0108000B6FE0200DB04E34AAF66C1DADFF6967"
    RegistrationType="ContentType"
    Sequence="108"
    Title="Test1"
    Description="Test1"
    >

    <CommandUIExtension>
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition
          Location="Ribbon.ListForm.Display">
          <Tab
            Id="Ribbon.CustomTabExample"
            Title="My Custom Tab"
            Description="This holds my custom commands!"
            Sequence="501">
            <Scaling
              Id="Ribbon.CustomTabExample.Scaling">
              <MaxSize
                Id="Ribbon.CustomTabExample.MaxSize"
                GroupId="Ribbon.CustomTabExample.CustomGroupExample"
                Size="OneLargeTwoMedium"/>
              <Scale
                Id="Ribbon.CustomTabExample.Scaling.CustomTabScaling"
                GroupId="Ribbon.CustomTabExample.CustomGroupExample"
                Size="OneLargeTwoMedium" />
            </Scaling>
            <Groups Id="Ribbon.CustomTabExample.Groups">
              <Group
                Id="Ribbon.CustomTabExample.CustomGroupExample"
                Description="This is a custom group!"
                Title="Custom Group"
                Sequence="52"
                Template="Ribbon.Templates.CustomTemplateExample">
                <Controls Id="Ribbon.CustomTabExample.CustomGroupExample.Controls">
                  <Button
                    Id="Ribbon.CustomTabExample.CustomGroupExample.HelloWorld"
                    Command="CustomTabExample.HelloWorldCommand"
                    Sequence="15"
                    Description="Says hello to the World!"
                    LabelText="Hello, World!"
                    TemplateAlias="cust1"/>
                  <Button
                    Id="Ribbon.CustomTabExample.CustomGroupExample.GoodbyeWorld"
                    Command="CustomTabExample.GoodbyeWorldCommand"
                    Sequence="17"
                    Description="Says good-bye to the World!"
                    LabelText="Good-bye, World!"
                    TemplateAlias="cust2"/>
                  <Button
                    Id="Ribbon.CustomTabExample.CustomGroupExample.LoveWorld"
                    Command="CustomTabExample.LoveWorldCommand"
                    Sequence="19"
                    Description="Says I love the World!"
                    LabelText="I love you, World!"
                    TemplateAlias="cust3"/>
                </Controls>
              </Group>
            </Groups>
          </Tab>
        </CommandUIDefinition>
        <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Templates._children">
          <GroupTemplate Id="Ribbon.Templates.CustomTemplateExample">
            <Layout
              Title="OneLargeTwoMedium"
              LayoutTitle="OneLargeTwoMedium">
              <Section Alignment="Top" Type="OneRow">
                <Row>
                  <ControlRef DisplayMode="Large" TemplateAlias="cust1" />
                </Row>
              </Section>
              <Section Alignment="Top" Type="TwoRow">
                <Row>
                  <ControlRef DisplayMode="Medium" TemplateAlias="cust2" />
                </Row>
                <Row>
                  <ControlRef DisplayMode="Medium" TemplateAlias="cust3" />
                </Row>
              </Section>
            </Layout>
          </GroupTemplate>
        </CommandUIDefinition>
      </CommandUIDefinitions>
      <CommandUIHandlers>
        <CommandUIHandler
          Command="CustomTabExample.HelloWorldCommand"
          CommandAction="javascript:alert('Hello, world!');" />
        <CommandUIHandler
          Command="CustomTabExample.GoodbyeWorldCommand"
          CommandAction="javascript:alert('Good-bye, world!');" />
        <CommandUIHandler
          Command="CustomTabExample.LoveWorldCommand"
          CommandAction="javascript:alert('I love you, world!');" />
      </CommandUIHandlers>
    </CommandUIExtension>
  </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

But I'm not sure how to change the location to make it show where I want?
Atm it shows a tab named "Custom Commands" and a button named "Test1"

How would I change this so that my three buttons on my custom action display?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Basically there are multiple ways to check that:

1. Have a look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb802730.aspx for a list of "locations"
2. For those in Ribbon you can have a look in 14-Hive under the location CMDUI.xml (in location %ProgramFiles%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\14\TEMPLATE\GLOBAL\XML) more details find @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee537543.aspx

In your example if i'm not mistaken the it should create a NEW Templates in the Display Form for a LIST and the Ribbon.Templates._children is where your NEW buttons will be added (does NOT exist by default!)

Hope it helps,
C:\Marius